# How to get Doxygen to ignore inheritance relationship?

Tags: c++, inheritance, doxygen

I'm trying to get Doxygen to ignore an inheritance relationship when drawing collaboration diagrams.

Let's say my class definition looks like this:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
}
```

Now, when I run Doxygen, I don't want to see Base class in the generated collaboration diagram.

At first glance, it seems that the cleanest way to do this would be to use the `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` directive in my Doxyfile.  Specifically:

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = Base
```

However, I've found that this does not work: The Base class still shows up in my collaboration diagram for Derived.  I've tried this on both Doxygen `1.8.6` and `1.8.11` and with different permutations of Base wildcards (Base*, *as*, etc), same behavior.  *The Base class always shows up in my collaboration diagram.*

To be fair, I have found 2 workarounds, but they both involve putting conditional statements into my code.  For completeness, I'll include both here:

**First Workaround Method:**

```
class Derived : 
#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
    public Base
#endif /* DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS */
{
  ...
}
```

Then ensure that the following two directives are set inside the Doxyfile:

```
PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
```

**Second Workaround Method:**

```
class Derived : 
/// @cond DOXYGEN_IGNORE
        public Base
/// @endcond
{
  ...
}
```

To be clear, these workarounds do indeed make Doxygen ignore the inheritance relationship, but I'd prefer not to unnecessarily pollute my code base, especially if there's a better / cleaner way to accomplish my goal.

My question is -- Why doesn't `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` make Doxygen ignore my Base class when it draws the collaboration diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If i am not mistaken, `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS` prevents Doxygen from generating documentation for the excluded symbols, but it does not hide them. This means Doxygen won't generate documentation for your `Base` class, but it will still mention it as the base class of `Derived`, just like if `Derived` inherited from a class provided by an external library, the name of the class provided by the library would appear in the collaboration diagram.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set `HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = YES`. Then the *undocumented* class `Base` will not be shown on the collaboration diagram.