# Linked Qt documentation to own Doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

I created a HMI project on Qt Creator (7.0.1 with Qt 6.2.3) in one hand and a C++ (C++ 20) library through Visual Studio in the other hand.

The first step was to create a Doxygen documentation for the library, which is working well for now using a Doxyfile configuration file.

Next, I add the documentation about my own HMI class adding the sources code path in the Doxyfile. It is also working but I didn't have the link to the Qt object (such as QString, ...).

So I modify my Doxyfile to include all tags of my Qt version in the TAGFILES paramater (example: *c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/activeqt/activeqt.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/*). Doing this allowed me to have indeed the links to the Qt objects but also a lot of public members I don't want to see on my documentation (example: the *setToolButtonStyle* method of the MainWindow class. Here is a snapshot of the beginning (because there are thousands of methods unwanted) :

[image]

How can I exclude all these methods from the Qt object and keep only the methods of my own class ?

Here is my DoxyFile:

```
    PROJECT_NAME           = "NEW SUPRA"
    PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.0.0
    PROJECT_BRIEF          = "The new version of the SDK for Capture software"
    PROJECT_LOGO           = ../i2SSDKLinear/LogoI2S_doc.png
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = output
    INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = YES
    NUM_PROC_THREADS       = 0
    EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
    EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
    INPUT                  = ../i2SSDKLinear \
                             ../IHM/IHM_Test
    IMAGE_PATH             = ../i2SSDKLinear
    GENERATE_QHP           = YES
    QCH_FILE               = ../MyDoc.qch
    QHP_NAMESPACE          = i2s.newSupra.1.0
    QHG_LOCATION           = C:/Qt/Tools/QtDesignStudio/qt6_design_studio_reduced_version/bin/qhelpgenerator.exe
    DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
    GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
    GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
    GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = YES
    TAGFILES               = c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/activeqt/activeqt.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qdoc/qdoc.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qt3d/qt3d.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtbluetooth/qtbluetooth.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtconcurrent/qtconcurrent.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtcore/qtcore.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtgui/qtgui.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtlabsplatform/qtlabsplatform.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtnetwork/qtnetwork.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtnfc/qtnfc.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtpositioning/qtpositioning.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtprintsupport/qtprintsupport.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtqml/qtqml.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtquick/qtquick.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtquickcontrols/qtquickcontrols.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtscxml/qtscxml.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtsensors/qtsensors.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtserialbus/qtserialbus.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtsql/qtsql.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtsvg/qtsvg.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qttestlib/qttestlib.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtwebchannel/qtwebchannel.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtwebsockets/qtwebsockets.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtwidgets/qtwidgets.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/ \
                             c:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4/qtxml/qtxml.tags=https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/
    HAVE_DOT               = YES
    CALL_GRAPH             = YES
    CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
    DIR_GRAPH_MAX_DEPTH    = 5
```

**UPDATE 1:** Find half the solution

Preparing an example to give more detail, I saw something about the *INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB* which will be set to *YES*. Setting it to *NO* will resolve half the issue because I have not anymore all these methods directly shown. But now I have section about all additional inherited members:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Source code example

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myFunction("test");
    ui->label->setText(str);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::myFunction(QString text)
{
    str = text;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void myFunction(QString text);
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QString str;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**UPDATE 3 :** Workaround found

Using workarounds of [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312241/how-to-get-doxygen-to-ignore-inheritance-relationship).

Comment: Doxygen documents every `public` or `protected` members and ignore `private` members by default (it may be changed though). Usually, to exclude some functions specifically, you can use the `\private` doxygen tag so that the member will be treated as if it was declared `private`. But in your case, since you import the references from external sources (which you can't modify), I'm not sure if it is possible to do what you want.

Comment: Is it correct that you use doxygen version 1.9.4? It looks to me that around `INPUT                  = ../i2SSDKLinear ../IHM/IHM_Test
    INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
    #
    #
                             *.cc \` some information is missing (use `doxygen -x Doxyfile` for a more compact list!). From wheer did you download the Qt tag files?

Comment: @albert yes it is my version. The first folder contains my c++ lib and the IHM/IHM/Test the HMI sources. And I find the tag in another post on stackoverflow :  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323207/doxygen-external-link-to-qt-classes)

Comment: In the referenced post I see: `FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \`  so something went wrong at your side when copying. Please show a small example exhibiting the problem. I see that the tag files come with the Qt distribution?

Comment: I only copied the part with the TAGFILES. Yes the tag files are in the installation folder of Qt. I update my post in few seconds to add news of my "issue".

Comment: I assume that your class extends the Qt classes `QMainWindow`. `QObject`, `QWidget` ...? So actually the function of the extended classes are also available. Maybe your problem is in the same category as the problem mentioned in https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9185 (with proposed pull request: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9247)

Comment: I added my example to the post. I have a classic mainwindow yes. I will see your link later thanks.

Comment: @albert what do i have to do with this commit ? Because I installed Doxygen from the binary and not the source so I have not the same directory hierarchy.

Comment: The idea that I get is that you would like to see the base class names but not the inherited functions etc from these classes. The mentioned issue has a similar purpose. Here the OP created the tag file without file names and members. What could you do? Test doxygen with the proposed patch to see whether or not it fixes you problem as well. How to accomplish it? Compile doxygen from source and apply the patch to it. Modify your tag files by removing the line referring the `filename` and also the members of the classes.  Quite a bit of work, but would show whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a workaround finally following the workarounds proposed by another user on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312241/how-to-get-doxygen-to-ignore-inheritance-relationship).